# Uniform convergence of sequence of partial sums.Help please

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Show that each sequence of partial sums and its derivative converges uniformly on their respective intervals.

a) $$ S_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(1 + nx)^2}, x \in (0,\infty)$$

$$ S_n'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{-2}{(1 + nx)^3}, x \in (0,\infty)$$

b)$$S_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n e^{-nx}, x \in(0,\infty)$$

$$S_n'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n -ne^{-nx}, x \in(0,\infty)$$

for part a) I believe I can make use of the following  $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(1+nx)^2} < \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(nx)^2} = \frac{1}{x^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$$ so the infinite series converges.I know that I need to use Weierstrass M-Test and the Comparison test to show that the sequences $\{S_n(x)\}$ and $\{S_n'(x)\}$ converge uniformly on $(0,\infty)$

Similarly, for part b) 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-nx} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(e^{-x}\right)^n$$ which shows the infinite series is a geometric series and converges.

I need help showing that $\{S_n(x)\}$ and $\{S_n'(x)\}$ converge uniformly on $(0,\infty)$ for part a) and b).I think I need to show that it converges uniformly on$[a,\infty)$ for every $a>0$ which would hold for all $x\in(0,\infty)$.But im not sure..help anyone?

Comment: The uniform convergence of the given series seems doubtful, if we are dealing with $(0,\infty)$, for the "tail" is large when $x$ is close to $0$. By the way,

Comment: @AndréNicolas can I do this $ S_n(x)=\sum_{n=1}^n \frac{1}{(1 + nx)^2} <  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(1 + nx)^2} < \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(nx)^2} $which converges , thus $S_n(x)=\sum_{n=1}^n \frac{1}{(1 + nx)^2} $converges by Weierstrass M-Test

Comment: The series definitely converges, by Comparison. It is the uniformity of the convergence that is problematic.

Comment: @AndréNicolas The problem I'm having is showing that the partial sum $\{S_n(x)\}$ converge uniformly on $(0,\infty)$.If I can do so then I would be able to show that $\{S_n'(x)\}$ converges uniformly also.

Comment: I misread the question. am a little puzzled. what do you mean by $\sum_{n=1}^n \frac{1}{(1+nx)^2}$? Do you mean $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(1+kx)^2}$? Please check the original: I do not believe someone would use the same symbol for the dummy variable of summation and the top end of the summation.

Answer (score 0):

You have already received clear comments and answers; so, what I shall add is quite marginal but I thought that it could be of interest to you. 
$$S_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(1 + kx)^2}=\frac{\psi ^{(1)}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)-\psi
   ^{(1)}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}+n\right)}{x^2}$$ $$S_n'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{-2}{(1 + kx)^3} =\frac{\psi ^{(2)}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)-\psi
   ^{(2)}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}+n\right)}{x^3}$$ If $n$ goes to $\infty$, the second term in each numerator disappears.

As already told by  André Nicolas, the only problems appear for $x=0$. For the remaining, the convergence is quite clear.